# Dynamically adjusting Y axis of a graph produced by plotly.graph_objects

Tags: python, plotly

[image]

The graph above is created by using the following code.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

candlestick = go.Candlestick(x=data.index,
                        open=data.open,
                        high=data.high,
                        low=data.low,
                        close=data.close,
                        increasing_line_color='red',
                        decreasing_line_color='green')
fig = go.Figure(data=[candlestick])
fig.show()
```

After the graph is generated, I can change its X axis by clicking "Zoom in" and "Zoom out" buttons on the top right corner.

However, I can't find any way to change its Y axis. I mean, for example, I want to set the minimum value of Y axis to 175, and the maximum value of Y axis to 177.

Is it possible to dynamically change the range of Y axis AFTER the graph is generated?

I know I can use `fig.update_yaxes(range=[175,177])` to update the range of Y axis. But running this command requires me to restart my program, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: Try this:`fig.update_yaxes(range=[175,177])`

Comment: `fig.update_yaxes(range=[175,177])` This command must be run before the graph is generated. Is it possible to change its range after the graph is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create the following solution based on [this document](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks).

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go

candlestick = go.Candlestick(x=data.index,
                        open=data.open,
                        high=data.high,
                        low=data.low,
                        close=data.close,
                        increasing_line_color='red',
                        decreasing_line_color='green')
fig = go.Figure(data=[candlestick])

def get_start_end_range(rng):
    if rng:
        if "xaxis.range" in rng.keys():
            return rng['xaxis.range'][0], rng['xaxis.range'][1]
        if 'xaxis.range[0]' in rng.keys():
            return rng['xaxis.range[0]'], rng['xaxis.range[1]']
    return None, None

app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Signals Graph'),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='signals-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

# Use callback to dynamically adjust the scale of Y axis 
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id="signals-graph", component_property="figure"),
    Input(component_id="signals-graph", component_property="relayoutData"),
)                
def scaleYaxis(rng):
    print(f"rng: {rng}")
    xstart, xend = get_start_end_range(rng)
    if xstart != None:
        try:
            range_data = data.loc[
                xstart : xend,
                ["high", "low", "open", "close"],
            ]
            if len(range_data) > 0:
                fig["layout"]["yaxis"]["range"] = [range_data['low'].min()*0.95, range_data['high'].max()*1.05]
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Something wrong occured: {e}")
        finally:
            print(f"update x axis: {[xstart, xend]}")
            fig["layout"]["xaxis"]["range"] = [xstart, xend]
    return fig
app.run_server()
```

The solution above uses callback to dynamically adjust the scale of Y axis.

The above code would crate a server listening to port 8050 at `127.0.0.1`.

You can visit `http://127.0.0.1:8050` to see this graph.

Comment: I used your code, but I cannot resize the graph. To me it looks like the function scaleYaxis is unused, and I'm note sure where to call it

Answer (score 0):

The graph can be updated with `fig.update_*`. I will answer with an example from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/#simple-candlestick-with-pandas), where the y-axis is restricted.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'],
                high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'],
                close=df['AAPL.Close'])])

fig.update_yaxes(range=[100,120])
fig.show()
```

[image]

**Example without y-axis restriction**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do it myself and this worked for me:

PS: I was changing some names while posting to remove my specific names and adjust to your variables names. Sorry if I introduced some typos.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go


app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='graph',
        figure=go.Figure(
            data=[go.Candlestick(
                x=data.index,
                open=data.open,
                high=data.high,
                low=data.low,
                close=data.close,
            )]
        ),
        config={'scrollZoom': True}
    )
])

@app.callback(
    Output('graph', 'figure'),
    Input('graph', 'relayoutData'),
)
def update_y_axis(relayoutData):
    if relayoutData is None or 'xaxis.range[0]' not in relayoutData:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    x0, x1 = pd.to_datetime(relayoutData['xaxis.range[0]']), pd.to_datetime(relayoutData['xaxis.range[1]'])
    y0, y1 = data.loc[x0:x1, ['Low', 'High']].min()[0], data.loc[x0:x1, ['Low', 'High']].max()[0]
    
    # Add a 5% margin to the y-axis range
    y_margin = (y1 - y0) * 0.05
    y0 = y0 - y_margin
    y1 = y1 + y_margin

    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=data.index,
                open=data.open,
                high=data.high,
                low=data.low,
                close=data.close,)])
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_range=[x0, x1], yaxis_range=[y0, y1])
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```